# Default sample test throwing triggerUncaughtException error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

Brand new project is throwing the below error

```
PASS  client/src/App.test.js
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the re
ason "Error: Network Error".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

It says its still a PASS, but why is it throwing this exception?

My app.test.js file below

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';



test('renders product list', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Products/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Turned out a child component was making an axios call without a .catch(error....

Answer (score 1):

Child component was making a api call with axios and not handling the exception.